# How to judge Time Limit for a constraint bound coding?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have seen many coding sites stating time limits and size of source code constraints to be considered while submitting any solution of a problem. I never make out how can i check whether my code would pass or not like if its exponential time limit is doubtful, or if O(n^2) maybe 2 sec depending on size of input. But how can i get a rough idea that this much size of test case will pass in the stated time? 
Some good examples would be helpful.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation - The actual time a program runs depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some rules of thumb, but a lot depends on the hardware/programming language the judge system is using. The best way is to make some tests like for loops or putting random numbers in a priority queue, just to get a feeling for it.

Mostly if you need more than 10^7 steps (which can consist of several simple operations), than you have to watch out for time out. That means:

1. If running time is O(n!), than n>11 is already critical: you have at least 10^7 operations and it is a lot.
2. If running time is O(2^n), than it is safe for n<=20, but too risky for n>25
3. If running time is O(n^3), than n should be around 300.
4. For O(n^2), n=5000 could be Ok but 10000 would very probable fail.
5. For n<=200000, algorithms with O(nlogn) are mostly ok.
6. For n<=10^7 linear running times are Ok, after that you would need sublinear algorithms.

But, as already said, these numbers can vary depending on the judging system